# How to safely store videos on iOS device (encrypted)?

Tags: ios, video, encryption, stream, adobe

I'm building an app that is supposed to play video streams (f4v) from Adobe Media Server.

One of the features requires the videos on the device for offline playing. These are premium subscription only videos and we would like registered users only to be able to play them.

Is there any way that I can store them on the iDevice, possibly encrypted, so the videos can't be stolen even if the filesystem on the device is being accessed ?

Comment: You can choose any encryption you like, however you will also need to have some key on the device (pers user preferable) which is the video is leaked this will also leak. So you need to really obscure it.

Comment: Protecting content from a device user is very difficult, you need DRM and a DRM server.

Comment: @rckoenes - Would you be so kind to give us a little more details ?

Comment: @MilenRadkov as in code, no I can't. You will have to do your own research. Apple has include some nice crypto libraries in iOS which allow you to encrypt en decrypt data. Apple docs will provide you with some samples: [Encryption in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172-CH9-SW14)

Comment: @rckoenes - Thank you.